# Saving R plot in SVG or pdf keeping the font

Tags: r, pdf, svg, plot, fonts

I'm pretty new in R. I'm doing my plots using one of my favorite fonts, Charter BT. I use thar font in inkscape, LaTeX, everywhere!!!. A few days ago everything in R was working correctly, but today, when I try to save any plot, the font just gone. I try to use other font more common, like Times New Roman, but the problem is not the font.

```
    windowsFonts(A=windowsFont("Charter BT"))      
    par(pty="s", cex.axis=1, las=1, cex.lab=1, family = "A")
    a1=c(22.02, 23.83,  26.67,  25.38,  25.49,  23.50,  25.90,  24.89, 25)
    a2=c(21.49, 22.67,  24.62,  24.18,  22.78,  22.56,  24.46,  23.79, 25)
    a3=c(20.33, 21.67,  24.67,  22.45,  22.29,  21.95,  20.49,  21.81, 25)
    a4=c(20.33, 21.67,  24.67,  22.45,  22.29,  21.95,  20.49,  21.81, 25)
    boxplot(
      quantile(a1,type=6),
      quantile(a2,type=6),
      quantile(a3,type=6),
      quantile(a4,type=6),
      names=c("a1","a2","a3", "a4"),
      ylab="Valor", ylim=c(20,28), col=rainbow(4))
    legend("top", inset = -0.2, legend=c("a1","a2","a3", "a4"),
fill=rainbow(4), horiz=TRUE, cex=0.8, xpd=TRUE)
```

I get in R

[image]

But when I save in pdf

[image]

How can I solve that problem??
Any suggestion, help??

Thanks

Comment: Probably set the font inside of the graphics device: `pdf(file=myFilePath, ...);  windowsFonts(A=windowsFont("Charter BT")); par(pty="s", ...` and so on. Then, once you've called `boxplot`, follow it with `dev.off()`.

Comment: @lmo It didn't work :(

Comment: `pdf` got a `family` parameter ...